# Why is the Fisher information of a one-parameter family of exponential distributions the inverse of the variance?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, variance, exponential-family, fisher-information

Let
$$
f(x; \lambda) = h(x) e^{\eta(\lambda) J(x) + \xi(\lambda)}
$$
be a one-parameter family of distributions. In my course notes, it is claimed that
\begin{align}
I(\lambda) &:= \mathbb{E}_\lambda\left[ \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial\lambda} \log f(x;\lambda) \right)^2 \right]\\& = \frac{1}{\mathrm{var}_\lambda (J(X))},
\end{align}
given $\mathbb{E}_\lambda(T(X)) = \lambda$. We also assume that all functions are "nice", in the sense that they are all continuously differentiable and that differentiation with respect to $\lambda$ commutes with integration over $x$.

What I tried was using the fact that under these nice regularity conditions, $I(\lambda) = -\mathbb{E} \left(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial^2\lambda} \log f(x;\lambda) \right)$, but then all I get is $I(\lambda) = -\mathbb{E}(\eta''(\lambda) T(x) + \xi''(\lambda)) = -\eta''(\lambda) \lambda - \xi''(\lambda).$ I have no idea how to relate this to the variance.

Comment: It is because in exponential families, variance of $T$ attains Cramer-Rao lower bound for $\lambda$. This follows by studying the equality condition of Cramer-Rao inequality.

Comment: Ok got it, thank you!

Comment: @StubbornAtom could you make your comment as an answer? This would complete the post.